# ironpython winform keyboard polling

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard, ironpython

I am using ironpython to make a winform application.  I need to be able to be constantly polling the keyboard for user input.  I've tried a few things but haven't been able to get anything to work.  I am working in visual studio 2012. Is there a way to do this keyboard polling?

Answer (score 0):

One would expect to use the .net Keyboard class and methods from System.Windows.Input.  However, when I try to import that namespace, I only find ICommand implemented.  I am on IronPython 2.7.4.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows')
import System.Windows.Input as Input

dir(Input)
```

Sadly, this just yields:

```
['ICommand']
```

So I guess the way to do it in IronPython is to go look up input handling for Python :(